# Is it possible to have a Textbox show calendar dropdown?

Tags: c#, winforms

Without place a TextBox over a Calendar control and hiding/showing controls and synchronizing values between controls, is it possible to have a Textbox and a button next to it, that when clicked, shows the calendar dropdown?

I would use the `DateTimePicker` control, however I want to set the value to `NULL` without having to show & use the checkbox.

I also want that the control is empty without any default date which is grayed out.

Implementing a custom control based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044968/get-date-in-text-box-from-month-calendar-with-button-in-c-sharp) is trivial, but I was wondering if a calendar dropdown can be shown without the need to have a hidden `DateTimePicker`.

Comment: To answer your question, **YES**.

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044968/get-date-in-text-box-from-month-calendar-with-button-in-c-sharp

Comment: Whats the problem with `DateTimePicker` control and why do you want to achieve this. You are going primitive.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much the definition of a `DateTimePicker`...

Comment: In question is explanation why `DateTimePicker` cannot be an answer

Comment: The question was editted about 3 times after I submitted this answer. I did not mean to critique, but to simply remind of a control that might well do the job. When I saw the more speicfic requirements of the OP, I tried to find a solution baed on the MonthCalendar tool, but haven't yet came up with a result.